# Cantor Product Expansion

Tags: infinite-product

I found the following definition of a *Cantor Product* expansion of $x \in [0, 1)$ in a book:

Let $r(x) = \lfloor \frac{x}{1 - x} \rfloor$, and define $T(x) = x \frac{r(x) + 1}{r(x)}$. Then (I'm told)

\begin{align*}
x & = \prod_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{r_{k}(x)}{r_{k}(x) + 1}
\end{align*}

where $r_{k} = r \circ T^{k}$.

Here's what I have.

\begin{align*}
x & = T^{K + 1}(x) \prod_{k = 0}^{K} \frac{r_{k}(x)}{r_{k}(x) + 1}
\end{align*}

I think it should work if $T^{K}(x) \to 1$, but am not sure. Could somebody familiar with this please help out? Thanks.